# sorting data to provide top entries

Tags: logic, sorting

I have a table like below. Each row has store id, discount % for one of their coupons. Each store could have multiple coupons but (store+discount %) is a primary key. I would like to find out top 10 coupons (by decreasing order of discount %) but would like to get only 2 coupon from the same store. What is the most efficient way to do this? My logic involves sorting data multiple times. Is there a better and more efficient way?

Sample data in R:

```
df <- data.frame(Store=c("Lowes","Lowes","Lowes","Lowes","HD","HD","HD","ACE",
                         "ACE","Misc","Misc","Other","Other","Last","Last","Last"),
                 `discount_%`=c("60%","50%","40%","30%","60%","50%","40%","30%",
                                "20%","50%","30%","20%","10%","10%","5%","3%"),
                 check.names = FALSE)
```

1. my solution is ignore the store and sort the table by discount then
   create a ID. ID would represent coupons in descending order
2. Then by Store and discount create ID2 which would have rankings of
   coupons by store.
3. then filter all rows where ID2>2
4. then sort table by ID
5. take top 10 rows

The question that was posed to me was if this table has billions of rows then what is the most efficient (less computing power and time) way of getting our answer?

Comment: Sort everything by discount percent, then go over the coupons in decreasing order of discount. Pick up coupons, throwing a coupon away if you already have two from the same store, until you have 10 coupons in your hand.

Comment: would it be possible to provide r/python code for your logic so that I can test your approach vs my approach?

Comment: Certainly, if you wrote that code.